# ng-class not working in AngularJS when defined with scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

For my below code `ng-class` isn't working:

#### HTML

```
<div class="row-content" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3 ng-class="{selected: searchType == 'news'}">
        <a ng-click="SetSearchType('news')" 
           href="javascript:void(0)">Alumni News</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3 ng-class="{selected: searchType == 'rss'}">
        <a ng-click="SetSearchType('rss')" 
           href="javascript:void(0)">Firm News</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AnjgularJS

```
var app = angular.module('ffApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.searchType = 'news';

    $scope.SetSearchType = function(type) {
        $scope.searchType = type;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Try in quotes: ng-class="{'selected': searchType === 'news'}"

Comment: Are you sure your view is using that controller?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think the problem is not in the code you posted, I reproduced it in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CM8Zocgl0jl1PaKBCQGe?p=preview) and it's working !

Comment: any error u getting in console ?

Comment: Hey guys, @FrankModica I have updated the code above. It's on the right controller

Comment: Please note that I'm using this for a tabbing and it works fine. There's no error showing on the console that is relevant to angular

Comment: And have you a CSS rule on the class `selected` ?

Comment: @JeanJacques I can inspect the element from the devTool. There no class defined. This is what I see <h3 ng-class="">

Comment: Hum, can you provide us the errors in the console please ? Even if it's not relevant to angular.

Comment: @JeanJacques Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxxxxx.com/news/default_draft.aspx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700|Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @lin Unfortunately not. I couldn't figureout the reason so I moved away from that method to another. I'm pretty sure I must have missed something. Must be a careless mistake

Comment: Please check my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with your CSS styles or your `$scope.selected` param. Please check this runnable **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3fjj0vv/)** and carefully compare it with your solution:

#### View

```
<div class="row-content" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3 ng-class="{'selected': searchType == 'news'}">
        <a ng-click="SetSearchType('news')" 
           href="javascript:void(0)">Alumni News</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3 ng-class="{'selected': searchType == 'rss'}">
        <a ng-click="SetSearchType('rss')" 
           href="javascript:void(0)">Firm News</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.searchType = 'news';

  $scope.SetSearchType = function(type) {
    $scope.searchType = type;
  }
});
```

#### CSS

```
.selected a {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: `ngClass` doesn't need quote, even without, it works. Take a look at [this plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/a3fjj0vv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

put your class in quotes ('')

```
<div class="row-content" ng-controller="MainController">
                <div class="tabs">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h3 ng-class="{'selected': searchType == 'news'}">
                            <a ng-click="SetSearchType('news')" href="javascript:void(0)">Alumni News</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h3 ng-class="{'selected': searchType == 'rss'}">
                            <a ng-click="SetSearchType('rss')" href="javascript:void(0)">Firm News</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
```